# Uncrustify to always remove space between type and * or &

Tags: uncrustify

I want Uncrustify to generate this no matter what:

```
TCHAR* p;
```

So that all of the following (if any) are converted to the above:

```
TCHAR * p;
TCHAR *p;
```

I also want:

```
TCHAR* f( TCHAR* p )
```

And I don't want:

```
TCHAR * f( TCHAR * p )
TCHAR *f( TCHAR *p )
```

Same for &.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

No in time, of cause, but maybe someone will need.

```
sp_before_ptr_star{ Ignore, Add, Remove, Force }
```

As I could understand, in your case

```
sp_before_ptr_star=Remove
```

You also may need

```
sp_after_ptr_star=Remove
```

Comment: Not enough reputation to vote you up. Thank you, though. It got me closer to a solution. This is what I've got so far:

sp_before_ptr_star = remove
sp_after_ptr_star  = force
sp_before_byref = remove
sp_after_byref = force